# What is the result of $x(at) * δ(t-k)$

Tags: convolution, signal-processing, dirac-delta

It seems rational  that $x(at) * δ(t-k) = x(at - ak)$. 
I tried to prove this: 
Let  $x_1(t) = x(at)$ then $x_1(t) * δ(t-k) = x_1(t-k) = x(at - ak)$. 
But I thought this as well:
$$x(at) * δ(t-k) = x(at) * δ\left(\frac{at-ak} a \right)  = a(x(at) * δ(at-ak)) = ax(at-ak)$$
Well I know that this may sound silly but I can't find where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dirac Delta is not zero at $t = k$ hence

$$x(at)\delta(t-k) = x(ak)$$

By the general distribution theory

$$f(x)\delta(x-a) = f(a)$$

**Convolution**

When it's about convolution, a simple rule reads:

\begin{align}
f(t)*\delta(t-a)=\int_0^t f(t-s)\delta(s-a)\,ds&=\begin{cases} 0, &t<a,\\ f(t-a) &t\ge a,\end{cases}=f(t-a)\theta(t-a),
\end{align}
where $\theta(t)$ denotes the unit step function.

Can you solve it for your function?

**The fastest solution**

Call $t-k = p$ in order to have

$$x(a(p+k))*\delta(p) = x(a(\tau + k))$$

In which we made use of the convolution identity

$$F[x\pm a]*\delta(x) = F[\tau \pm a]$$

Comment: Note that I'm using the * symbol (convolution)

Comment: Oh, I thought it was a multiplication! Then let me edit!

Comment: That's where I'm stuck I can't figure out how to solve it when instead of x(t)  there is x(at). Basically why I'm getting different results when I use the identity δ(at) = (1/a)  δ(t)

Comment: Try with $at = z$ ^_^

Comment: Dirac delta is zero when $t\neq k$

Comment: @Triatticus Aye, my error. Fixed.

Comment: No problem, otherwise looks like a good answer

Comment: Yes I tried and I got a result but when I applied another method the result was different. What's wrong with the second method? Maybe my question is misleading?

Comment: I will write the answer in a while!

Comment: @ArtificialIntelligence The RHS of the second (general case) equation should be $f(a) \delta(x-a)$, that is an impulse at $x=a$ of amplitude $f(a)$. The way the RHS is written implies the constant function $f(a)$ for all $x$ (similar remark for the first equation). Also, in signal processing at least, the convolution limits are typically considered to be $-\infty$ to $\infty$ and the result is $f(t-a)$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Well I agree with your solution that's how I solved it too but why is the second method wrong? Where is my mistake?

Comment: @algorithmnoob The last part of your equation does not hold. 

$$a x(at)*\delta(at - ak) = a \frac{x(a (\tau -k))}{\left| a\right| }$$

Clearly if $a> 0$ they get simplified.

Comment: Where does $|a|$ come from?

Comment: @algorithmnoob Collect $a$ inside the $\delta$!

Comment: @algorithmnoob You basically took a redundant passage by writing the Delta in that way!

Comment: Let $at = u$ then $ax(u) * δ(u-ak) = a x(u-ak) = a x(at-ak) $. Why is that wrong?

Comment: It's a redundant and useless passage

Comment: What is wrong is the result, not the passage you took

Comment: I think I understood what was my mistake. I can't change the variable from $at$ to $u$ because the convolution is function of t. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

The way you "prove" $x(at)*\delta(t-k)=x(at-kt)$ is not correct. Note that, starting from the signal $x(t)$, two operations are performed in series:

1. A time scaling operation to the signal $x(t)$, resulting in the signal $y(t)=x(at)$
2. A shift of the signal $y(t)$ by $k$, resulting in the signal $z(t)=y(t)*\delta(t-k)=y(t-k)=x(a(t-k))=x(at-ak)$.

The second equation in the "alternative" proof does not hold.

Comment: That's exactly how I proved it. Maybe you mean the second proof which is definitely incorrect but where's the mistake?

Comment: @algorithmnoob Oh yeah, this is your proof as well, sorry for the misunderstanding. In the second proof, the second equation does not hold